# Unload ClassLoader to unload native library

Tags: java, tensorflow, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, classloader

I am developing an application and I want to be able to load and unload different versions of a native library, more specifically Tensorflow and Pytorch.
In principle, Garbage collecting the classloader that loaded the class that called System.load(native_library).
However, it might not seem to be the case for either Tensorflow or Pytorch.
Here is a sample program I made to try to load two different Tensorflow versions:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ForceUnload2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create ClassLoader with wanted JARs
        String file1 = "/home/carlos/Documents/test/tensorflow_0.3.3_linux_cpu/";
        URLClassLoader cl1 = new URLClassLoader(getURLs(file1));
        // Load native library of Tensorflow
        Class<?> ca1 = cl1.loadClass("org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader");
        Class<?> ca3 = cl1.loadClass("org.tensorflow.internal.c_api.global.tensorflow");
        Method mm1 = ca1.getMethod("load", Class.class);
        mm1.invoke(null, ca3);
        // REmove references and try to garbage collect
        ca1 = null;
        mm1 = null;
        cl1.close();
        cl1 = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.gc();

        System.gc();

        // Create ClassLoader for the second Tensorflow version
        String file = "/home/carlos/Documents/test/tensorflow_0.2.0_linux_cpu";
        URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(getURLs(file));
        // Load the second native library
        Class<?> ca = cl.loadClass("org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader");
        Class<?> ca2 = cl.loadClass("org.tensorflow.internal.c_api.global.tensorflow");
        Method mm = ca.getMethod("load", Class.class);
        mm.invoke(null, ca2);
        // REmove all references to garbage collect
        ca2 = null;
        ca = null;
        mm = null;
        cl.close();
        cl = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.gc();
    }
    
    public static URL[] getURLs(String file) throws MalformedURLException {
        File[] fs = new File(file).listFiles();
        URL[] urls = new URL[fs.length];
        int c = 0;
        for (File f : fs) {
            urls[c ++] = f.toURI().toURL();
        }
        return urls;
    }
}
```

where file1 and file are the directories containing the needed JARs to load the native library.
I have also tried to force unload the native libraries with the following:

```
Field field = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("nativeLibraries");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object lib = field.get(cls1);
        Vector libs = (Vector) field.get(cls1);
        for (Object o : libs) {
            Method finalize = o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("finalize", new Class[0]);
            finalize.setAccessible(true);
            finalize.invoke(o, new Object[0]);
        }
```

This trick (I know it is very bad practice) allows the classloader to be garbage collected, but still loading the second version of the same native library causes an error, the same as if the native library had not been unloaded (the native library has not been unloaded then??).

**EDIT:**

As per @Holger answer I have done a couple of changes in the code addig a PhantomReference (which honestly I don't know if I have done it correctly). It seems that the URLClassLoader is not even queued for garbage collection. Here is the edited code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class ForceUnload2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create ClassLoader with wanted JARs
        String dir1 = "/home/carlos/Documents/test/tensorflow_0.3.3_linux_cpu/";
        ReferenceQueue<URLClassLoader> referenceQueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
        LargeObjectFinalizer phantomRefClassloader = load(dir1, referenceQueue);
        
        System.out.println(phantomRefClassloader.isEnqueued());

        Reference<?> referenceFromQueue;
        // Call System.gc() until the rederence is poll()
        while((referenceFromQueue = referenceQueue.poll()) == null) {
            System.gc();
            System.runFinalization();
        }
        ((LargeObjectFinalizer)referenceFromQueue).finalizeResources();
        referenceFromQueue.clear();
        referenceQueue = null;
        phantomRefClassloader = null;;
        referenceFromQueue = null;
        System.gc();
        

        // Create ClassLoader for the second Tensorflow version
        String dir2 = "/home/carlos/Documents/test/tensorflow_0.2.0_linux_cpu";
        ReferenceQueue<URLClassLoader> referenceQueue2 = new ReferenceQueue<>();
        load(dir2, referenceQueue2);
    }
    
    public static LargeObjectFinalizer load(String file1, ReferenceQueue<URLClassLoader> referenceQueue) throws Exception {
        LargeObjectFinalizer ref;
        try (URLClassLoader cls1 = new URLClassLoader(getURLs(file1))) {
            // Load native library of Tensorflow
            Class<?> ca1 = cls1.loadClass("org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader");
            Class<?> ca3 = cls1.loadClass("org.tensorflow.internal.c_api.global.tensorflow");
            Method mm1 = ca1.getMethod("load", Class.class);
            mm1.invoke(null, ca3);
            // Create phantom ref
            ref = new LargeObjectFinalizer(cls1, referenceQueue);
            cls1.close();
            System.out.println(ref.isEnqueued());
            // REmove references and try to garbage collect
            ca1 = null;
            ca3 = null;
            mm1 = null;
        }
        System.out.println(ref.isEnqueued());
        return ref;
    }
    
    public static URL[] getURLs(String file) throws MalformedURLException {
        File[] fs = new File(file).listFiles();
        URL[] urls = new URL[fs.length];
        int c = 0;
        for (File f : fs) {
            urls[c ++] = f.toURI().toURL();
        }
        return urls;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the LargeObjectFinalizer.I copied it from https://www.baeldung.com/java-phantom-reference

```
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class LargeObjectFinalizer extends PhantomReference<URLClassLoader> {

    public LargeObjectFinalizer(
            URLClassLoader referent, ReferenceQueue<? super URLClassLoader> q) {
        super(referent, q);
    }

    public void finalizeResources() {
        // free resources
        System.out.println("clearing ...");
    }
}
```

Regards,
Carlos

Comment: You should use a `PhantomReference` and `ReferenceQueue` to find out whether and when the `URLClassLoader` has been collected, rather than making guesswork like calling `System.gc()` ten times. This works best when refactoring the duplicated code into a method. Then, you don’t need to set any variable to `null`. Use `try(…) {}` to safely close the class loader but return a `PhantomReference` encapsulating the loader to the caller. The caller then may `poll()` the reference queue and call `System.gc()` until `poll()` returned the reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hoger . Just a couple of questions as I am not very familiar with this. By using `try(...){}` you mean something like `try(URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(...)){}`? ANd then, should the `PhantomReference` be inside the method with the duplicated code?

Comment: Yes, something like `try(URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(...)){ /* use cl */ return new PhantomReference(cl, queue); }`. The caller provides the queue as parameter and receives the phantom reference. It may then do something like `while(queue.poll() != reference) System.gc();` to wait until the loader has been collected.

Comment: Great, thank you! It works fine in Windows. However when I try the same thing in Linux it does not work. But I think the issue might be on the native libraries because I have also tried directly dlopen and dlclose on the .so files and I got the same error.

Comment: Note that one point of this refactoring was that now, all these `… = null` assignments are unnecessary. When you use JDK 9 or newer, calling `referenceFromQueue.clear();` is not necessary as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that it was double comprobation just in case haha! However I am still not able to unload certain libraries... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682562/jni-native-library-avoids-garbage-collection-and-unloading

Comment: That’s why I posted comments, rather than an answer. These steps did not guaranty to solve the problem, but were only to ensure that the problem is not on your side. It’s possible that a native library prevents objects from garbage collection. The next step is creating a heap dump and checking, which paths to root references exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answers sir! Just out of ignorance, after identifying the problem with the heap dump, will I be able to solve the issue on the JAva side, or should I tackle it from the C++ side?

Comment: That depends on the result of the analysis. It’s impossible to predict beforehand.